# How to change the type of an object property on an extended interface?

Tags: typescript

Example:

```js
interface Foo {
  myProp: string
  myObjectProp: {
    objProp1: string
    objProp2: number
  }
}

interface Bar extends Foo {
  myObjectProp: {
    objProp2: string // Error: Interface 'Bar' incorrectly extends interface 'Foo'
  }
}
```

How do I change the type of `objProp2` without having to completely redeclare the `myObjectProp` on the extended interface?

Comment: Are you trying to change it?  It's apparently `number` in both places.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad... But yes, I'm trying to change it to anything else

Comment: No, you can't extend `number` with `string` even *if* you "completely redeclare the `myObjectProp` on the extended interface", [see here](https://tsplay.dev/NlxrGN).  I'm therefore not sure what to do with this question; it seems you are operating under a false premise.

Comment: In order to make your code a [mre], please consider [edit]ing it either to be explicitly asking something like "can I change a property when extending", like `interface Foo {x: string, y: number}; interface Bar extends Foo {x: number}` *or* to be explicitly asking something like "can I extend an anonymous type without redeclaring it" like `interface Foo {x: {a: string}}; interface Bar extends Foo {x: {b: number}}`.  Right now it feels like it might be a mixture of both.

Comment: You're right. I was working with the premise that I could change the type of the `myObjectProp` as I could do with `myProp`. Because if I extend the same interface I can change the type of top level properties without any problem. I can do for example, change the type of `myProp` to `number` and TS accepts it.

Comment: What do you mean by "accepts" it?  [I see an error if you do that](https://tsplay.dev/wR9qQW).

Comment: You're right again. It seems something is buggy with my VS Code TS linter, it doesn't show any error while on editor, but the error appears when compilling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic types with default values.

```
interface Foo<T = ShapeA> {
  myProp: string
  myObjectProp: T
}

interface ShapeA {
  objProp1: string
  objProp2: number
}

interface ShapeB {
  objProp2: string
}

interface Bar extends Foo<ShapeB> {
  myObjectProp: {
    objProp2: string
  }
}
```

[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqyC8yAygBZwAOEAggHzIDeAsAFDLIC2AngApTrkAuZAGcwUUAHMWbLgHkARgCsICML35CcLAL4sWoSLEQpSFag2nJ0S9eQCMQ0eJBTWVm33IAmISACu7PLQOnrMBtDwSMRklABCFm7WirY+ImKSIcz64BHGyLFwUMgQAB6QIAAmwmiYWKZxdExuckoqap5CTWxsSSmO6S6WuszaQA)

Comment: Your playground code is different from what you posted; you put `objProp1` as optional in the playground but not here.  Can you discuss what you're doing here? It should be explicit if you're going to change things like that.

Comment: @jcalz I have updated my comment and the playground code with an even better example of polymorphism

Comment: Why are you rewriting the property in `Bar`?  Isn't `Foo<ShapeB>` enough without extension?  You could write `interface Bar extends Foo<ShapeB> {}` and it would be the same type.  It's also still not clear to me whether the question wants to keep `objProp1` inside `Bar`'s `myObjectProp` or not.

Comment: OP can do whatever he wants with generic types. I just took his example and showed how you can change the type definition of nested properties. Your examples are different approaches to the same solution, and they are all valid

Comment: @salmin-skenderovic I completely understood your answer and while it solves the problem, I want to wait a bit more and see if any other idea pops up. Than you.